# Dynamic broadcast registration for SMS_RECEIVED is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

Registering broadcast receiver for `SMS_RECEIVED` action in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

works as expected, `SmsReceiver.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` is called. 
Trying to register dyamically

```
 Intent inte = registerReceiver(
                 new SmsReceiver(), 
                 new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION));
```

`SmsReceiver.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` is never called.

*notice*

- **Device API Level is LOWER than 23** so it's not [runtime request permission problem](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
- tried `IntentFilter.setPriority(1000)` with no success.
- `registerReceiver` returns **null**

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Wrong action. It's `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can i fix that ?

Start by using the correct `Intent` action.

There are *two* action strings related to SMS delivery. What works for any app — and what you are using in the `<intent-filter>` — [is `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION). What only works for the user's chosen SMS client — and what you are trying to use with the `IntentFilter` — [is `SMS_DELIVER_ACTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_DELIVER_ACTION). These are not the same.

Comment: I changed to `SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION` and still was not working. Reason was that phone display was locked. After i unlocked a screen it started working.

Comment: @tchelidze: IIRC, receivers registered dynamically by an activity only receive broadcasts when they are in the foreground (i.e., not paused/stopped/destroyed). And, IIRC, activities get paused when the screen turns off and the lockscreen is put in place.