# SMS BroadcastReceiver not triggered when phone hasn't been used for a while?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-sms

I have an app that registers a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".smsprocessing.SmsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It has always been working perfectly fine when I'm testing it, but today I tried sending an SMS to a phone with the app installed which I hadn't touched for a few hours. The app has been working fine on this phone before while testing, but I've always tested it with the display on or within a few minutes after locking the screen.

It seems that my `BroadcastReceiver` wasn't triggered today when I hadn't used the phone for a few hours. The SMS was received and triggered the stock Messaging app, but my BroadcastReceiver was not triggered (or at least, the foreground service I'm starting from `onReceive()` wasn't started).

The phone in question is a Motorola Moto G running Android 4.4.4.

#### EDIT

When I connect the phone via USB minutes after it was supposed to have triggered the BroadcastReceiver, I see only two logs related to my app:

```
10-12 22:33:28.438 1039-1053/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.example.myapp for broadcast com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.smsprocessing.SmsBroadcastReceiver: pid=3554 uid=10230 gids={50230, 3003}
10-12 22:33:28.961 1039-4323/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.myapp (pid 3554) has died.
```

Here is the full log from when (I think) the SMS was received (I have prefixed the above two lines with `###`):

```
10-12 22:33:28.235 1039-1186/? I/PackageManager: Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
10-12 22:33:28.271 1039-4323/? I/PackageManager: Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
10-12 22:33:28.291 1039-1401/? I/PackageManager: Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
10-12 22:33:28.312 1039-1100/? I/PackageManager: Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
10-12 22:33:28.345 1039-1053/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.mms for broadcast com.android.mms/.transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver: pid=3524 uid=10030 gids={50030, 3003, 1028, 1015}10-12 22:33:28.345 1039-1053/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.mms for broadcast com.android.mms/.transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver: pid=3524 uid=10030 gids={50030, 3003, 1028, 1015}
### 10-12 22:33:28.438 1039-1053/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.example.myapp for broadcast com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.smsprocessing.SmsBroadcastReceiver: pid=3554 uid=10230 gids={50230, 3003}
10-12 22:33:28.635 1039-1093/? D/WifiService: Client connection lost with reason: 4
10-12 22:33:28.644 1039-1050/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2: pid=3571 uid=10010 gids={50010, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023}
10-12 22:33:28.645 1039-4321/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.gms (pid 2593) has died.
10-12 22:33:28.648 1039-4321/? W/ActivityManager: Service ServiceRecord{43d5d0e0 u0 com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsApiService} in process ProcessRecord{425f9028 2593:com.google.android.gms/u0a22} not same as in map: null
10-12 22:33:28.649 1039-4321/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService in 26259ms
    Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.checkin.CheckinService in 26259ms
    Service ServiceRecord{43116f88 u0 com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsBoundBrokerService} in process ProcessRecord{425f9028 2593:com.google.android.gms/u0a22} not same as in map: null
10-12 22:33:28.848 1039-1290/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.gms for service com.google.android.gms/.ads.identifier.service.AdvertisingIdService: pid=3618 uid=10022 gids={50022, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001, 3007, 2001, 3006}
### 10-12 22:33:28.961 1039-4323/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.myapp (pid 3554) has died.
10-12 22:33:29.279 1039-1313/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.apps.photos (pid 3476) has died.
10-12 22:33:29.998 1039-1049/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.gms.unstable (pid 3285) has died.
10-12 22:33:30.227 1039-1093/? D/WifiService: New client listening to asynchronous messages
10-12 22:33:30.422 263-349/? W/Vold: Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
10-12 22:33:30.425 263-349/? W/Vold: Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
10-12 22:33:30.483 1039-1100/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.gms.unstable for service com.google.android.gms/.droidguard.DroidGuardService: pid=3693 uid=10022 gids={50022, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001, 3007, 2001, 3006}
10-12 22:33:30.847 1039-4323/? I/ActivityManager: Process android.process.acore (pid 3571) has died.
10-12 22:33:31.308 1039-3556/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.android.mms (pid 3524) has died.
```

Comment: Do you see anything in logcat related to the intent you expect to be delivered?  The Android framework might log something that could provide a clue why it was not delivered to your app.  BTW, this [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113584/dynamic-broadcast-registration-for-sms-received-is-not-working) seems similar to yours.

Comment: @MichaelKrause See my edit with logs. I had a look at the other issue you linked to, but his issue was caused by registering the `BroadcastReceiver` manually in code, not in the Manifest like I have done...